# Is there a way to force a vuetify tooltip to close (Safari browser) on the click of the target element?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a web app using Vuetify 2.3.8 that has tooltips on various buttons. When using the Safari browser, after clicking a button that has a tooltip, the tooltip stays visible. I need it to disappear. Any ideas?

Here is the code for the element:

```
<v-tooltip top>
 <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
   <v-btn :disabled="disableDelete" @click="deleteLayer()" class="pt-1" height="30" icon v-on="on">
     <v-icon color="grey darken-3">delete</v-icon>
   </v-btn>
 </template>
 <span>Delete Selected</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

The tooltip works in all other tested browsers.

Comment: As there is no open event on the component I can't find any way to do it properly
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#api

Comment: @darrin have you considered using `v-model` 
 : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#visibility?

Comment: The answer is using the v-model and is only required for the Safari browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move `v-on="on"` to `v-icon`.